# Angular ngFor - is it possible to dynamically pass in a dummy array when the ngFor array is empty?

Tags: angular

Angular ngFor - is it possible to dynamically pass in a dummy array when the ngFor array is empty?

---

Currently, I am doing the following as a workaround. It works but wondering if it is possible to further reduce the code.

**Working:**

**Template:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of [] | skeletonLoadingCount:10 " >
  <span>repeated</span>
</div>
```

**Pipe:**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'skeletonLoadingCount'
})
export class SkeletonPipe<T = any> implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: number): any[] {
    if(!(Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0)) {
      return Array.from(Array(arg).keys());
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

---

**Expectation:**

Is it possible to do similar to the `trackBy` ngFor?

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of []; skeletonLoadingCount:10 " >
  <span>repeated</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do it in your code with || []

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop "on-fly" using `' '.repeat(10).split('')`. So you can use

```
<div *ngFor="let i of (list.length?list:' '.repeat(10).split(''))">
  repeat
</div>
```

Or even using a variable

```
count:number=10

<div *ngFor="let i of (list.length?list:' '.repeat(count).split(''))">
  repeat
</div>
```

But I'm not pretty sure the aim of do it

NOTE: You can also use a variable listToLoop and equal to your "list" or an array with 10 elements